# Save ONLY CSV attachments when email received - Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I have the following flow in Power Automate.

The trigger works fine

The actions work fine

The filter does not. It saves ALL the attachments rather than just the single named CSV file. I have tried several condition including `Ends with`, `Contains` and `Equals` with various strings for comparison but I always get all the attachments including the images etc.

Any help appreciated, I am still finding my feet with Power Automate.

[image: screen shot of Power Automate Flow]

These are the advanced settings in the trigger

[image: Screenshot of advanced settings in trigger.]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, your `Apply to each` loop is pointing to the original array of attachments that came in from the trigger.

It needs to point to the output from the `Filter array` operation.

Find the dynamic content from the output of the filter operation, change it to that, and it will work for you.

Comment: Is there a way find the output of the Filter Array? I assumed that attachments was coming from the filter array given that it was chosen from the dynamic list for that step.

Comment: Yeah, it’s in the dynamic content.